# jQuery .load() not working properly(?)

Tags: jquery, html

So I have a link `.button` that prepends an image to a div `#container` onclick.

```
$(".button").click(function(e) {
  $('#container').prepend("<img src='http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_ma4oz49mAq1r2cisro1_1280.png'>");
  $('#container').load(function(){
    alert('Finished Loading!');
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Once the image has been loaded, it fires a message. At least that's what I expect it to do. It isn't doing that though. When I put `#container *` on the load() function instead, it does. The jQuery docs say it works on the element and its sub-elements. So what am I missing here?

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axNn6/1/). You can add an asterisk to the selector for the load() to see that it works with it instead. I've tried appending an iframe instead of an image, too and the same thing happens. Note that I'm planning to pull ajax contents into it later and just testing with an image.

Am I doing something wrong or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind the load for image object and not container. Try this:

```
$(".button").click(function(e) {
  $('#container').prepend("<img src='http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_ma4oz49mAq1r2cisro1_1280.png' class='tst'>");
    $('.tst').load(function(){
      alert('Finished Loading!');
    });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

**[working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/axNn6/2/)**

Comment: That's true, but not reliable. To do it reliably, you have to bind the event **before** setting the image's `src`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: that need event delegation in that case. because image is getting generated here on append.

Comment: @ Milind: No, you just create the image first.

Comment: Okay so I can get this much. As I've mentioned, I'm planning to pull ajax content later instead but I guess I can get around that with this the same somehow. Can you guys explain though why just using `#container` doesn't work?

Comment: @user3047675: because image is loaded in image tag and not in container that you are trying to bind event with.

Comment: @user3047675: Because the `load` event doesn't bubble. Note: If you use this code, and the image is cached, you *are* going to miss the `load` event in some browsers.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(".button").click(function(e) {
  $('#container').prepend("<img src='http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_ma4oz49mAq1r2cisro1_1280.png' id='test'>");
    $('#test').load(function(){
      alert('Finished Loading!');
    });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: @user3047675  Your are checking for container which is already load so place a id to image and check on this.

Answer (score 0):

Load the image on document ready and hide the image. on button click show the image

```
$('#container').prepend("<img src='http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_ma4oz49mAq1r2cisro1_1280.png'>");
$('#container img').hide();

$(".button").click(function(e) {
     $('#container img').show();
        $('#container').load(function(){
          alert('Finished Loading!');
        });
      e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To reliably get the `load` event from the image, you must:

1. Bind the `load` event on the image, not the container, and
2. Do so *before* setting the `img`'s `src` property.

So: [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axNn6/3/)

```
$(".button").click(function(e) {
  $("<img>")
      .load(function(){
          alert('Finished Loading!');
      })
      .attr("src", "http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_ma4oz49mAq1r2cisro1_1280.png")
      .addClass("tst")
      .prependTo("#container");
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

If you set the `src` on the image before binding the `load` event, and the image is cached, you may miss the event entirely on some browsers. By ensuring that you have the event hooked *before* setting the `src`, you **know** you won't miss it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".button").click(function(e) {
  $('#container').prepend("<img src='http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_ma4oz49mAq1r2cisro1_1280.png' id='testimg'>");
  //$('#testimg').load(function(){
    $('#container').load('Load', '#testimg', function () { 
    alert('Finished load!');
  }



  );
  e.preventDefault();
});
```